# Unable to import RAML specification from Design Center to Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, anypoint-platform

I am unable to import RAML specification from Design Center to Anypoint Studio as I am receiving the following error:

[image: Anypoint Studio RAML Specification Import Error Screenshot].
I have tried the following to resolve the issue:

1. Re-downloading Anypoint Studio
2. Changing workspace location
3. Removing and adding Anypoint Platform credentials to Studio
4. Using different credentials in Studio

Also note that:

- The same error is occurring for both Anypoint Studio 6 & Anypoint Studio 7
- The error is shown when I am trying to import the RAML spec during project creation or importing the spec to existing project from the right-click menu.
- Anypoint Studio is configured with the Client ID & Client Secret in the Preferences > Anypoint Platform > API Manager
- I am able to search for my existing published APIs when searching for them in the Add Modules from Exchange window

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version of Studio 7? Currently it is version 7.5.1. Also, are there any errors or warnings for this API in Design Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some ongoing issue with Design Center
The issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

This usually attributes to some grammatical errors in your RAML/OAS specification in Design Center.  Even though the Design Center may not complain abt it, when you try to import that into Studio it will complain.  Check your usage of "example" vs "examples" in RAML spec.  If not, please upload a copy of your RAML spec.